# async generator with slow consumer

Tags: python, python-asyncio

If I have a slow consumer of an async generator that emits values at a quick frequency, and I only care about consuming the latest value (i.e. I'm not fussed about dropping values), is there a way to achieve this in an eloquent way? I've taken a look at [aiostream](https://aiostream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) but I couldn't seem to find anything that fits.

Here is a simple example:

```py
import asyncio
import aiostream

async def main():

    xs = aiostream.stream.count(interval=0.2)

    async with xs.stream() as stream:
        async for x in stream: # do something here to drop updates that aren't processed in time
            print(x)
            await asyncio.sleep(1.0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you to use a class that handles the external generator, since I don't know any source to do that.

The class can consume internally the generator in a task and keep only the last value. It's going to be like a wrapper over the generator you really want to consume.

```py
import asyncio

class RelaxedGenerator:

   def __init__(self, async_gen):
      self.last_value = None        # the last value generated
      self.consumed_last = True     # flags the last value as consumed
      self.async_gen = async_gen    # generator which we can drop values
      self.exhausted = False        # flags the generator as fully consumed

   @classmethod
   async def start(cls, async_gen):
      self = cls(async_gen())
      asyncio.create_task(self.generate())
      return self

   async def generate(self):
      # here you can consume the external async generator
      # and save only the last value for further process
      while True:
         try:
            self.last_value = await self.async_gen.__anext__()
            self.consumed_last = False
         except StopAsyncIteration:
            self.exhausted = True
            break

   async def stream(self):
      while not self.exhausted:
         if self.consumed_last:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.01)  # avoids block the loop
            continue
         self.consumed_last = True
         yield self.last_value
```

Testing with a simple generator:

```py
import asyncio
from random import uniform

async def numbers_stream(max_=100):
   next_int = -1
   while next_int < max_:
      next_int += 1
      yield next_int
      await asyncio.sleep(0.2)

async def main():
   gen = await RelaxedGenerator.start(numbers_stream)
   async for value in gen.stream():
      print(value, end=", ", flush=True)
      await asyncio.sleep(uniform(1, 2))

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
0, 6, 15, 21, 28, 38, 43, 48, 57, 65, 73, 81, 89, 96,
```

Other things to keep in mind is if you want to process the last value or if the generator you are working with is going to be exhausted or not in practice. Here I assume that you don't care about last value and the generator can be exhausted.

Comment: I did think that the best thing would be to do something like this, that is writing a wrapper class that does this. I don't love having to put in the
```
if self.consumed_last:
  await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
  continue
```
but I also don't see a more eloquent way than what you've written.
Thank you very much for your response and help!

Answer (score 1):

You could add a queue between your producer and consumer which forgets old results. Unfortunately, there is no implementation for it in the standard library, but it is almost there. If you check the implementation of `asyncio.Queue` you will notice the use of `collections.deque`, see https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/asyncio/queues.py#L49.
The `collections.deque` takes the optional argument `maxlen` to discard previously added items, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.
Making use of it, enables us to create our custom queue, which only keeps the last n items.

```py
import asyncio
import collections

class RollingQueue(asyncio.Queue):
    def _init(self, maxsize):
        self._queue = collections.deque(maxlen=maxsize)
        
    def full(self):
        return False
```

Now you could use this queue as follows:

```py
async def numbers(nmax):
    for n in range(nmax):
        yield n
        await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
        
async def fill_queue(producer, queue):
    async for item in producer:
        queue.put_nowait(item)
    queue.put_nowait(None)

queue1 = RollingQueue(1)
numgen = numbers(10)
task = fill_queue(numgen, queue1)
asyncio.create_task(task)
while True:
    res = await queue1.get()
    if res is None:
        break
    print(res)
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Where I set the queue size to 1 to just keep the last item as required in your question.

Comment: I think this along with the first proposed solution would make the most sense. Thank you very much for your response and help, this has been very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of the two provided answers, I came up with the following solution which seems to work quite well:

```py
import asyncio
import aiostream
import collections

class RollingQueue(asyncio.Queue):
    def _init(self, maxsize):
        self._queue = collections.deque(maxlen=maxsize)
        
    def full(self):
        return False

@aiostream.operator(pipable=True)
async def drop_stream(source, max_n=1):
    queue = RollingQueue(max_n)
    exhausted = False

    async def inner_task():
        async with aiostream.streamcontext(source) as streamer:
            async for item in streamer:
                queue.put_nowait(item)
        nonlocal exhausted
        exhausted = True

    task = asyncio.create_task(inner_task())
    try:
        while not exhausted:
            item = await queue.get()
            yield item
    finally:
        task.cancel()


async def main():

    xs = aiostream.stream.count(interval=0.2) | drop_stream.pipe(1) | aiostream.pipe.take(5)

    async with xs.stream() as stream:
        async for x in stream:
            print(x)
            await asyncio.sleep(1.0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```